# COUNT is MUCH slower than regular select

Tags: mysql, indexing, count

I have the following query:

```
SET @poly = (SELECT `polygon` FROM locations WHERE location_id = 65);

SELECT 
`listings`.`listing_id`
FROM `listings`
STRAIGHT_JOIN `listings_coords` ON `listings_coords`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`listing_id`


WHERE
`listings`.`country_id` = 223
AND `listings`.`active` = 1
AND `listings`.`published_flag` = 1

AND `listings`.`lat` BETWEEN 51.333436956522 AND 51.681263043478
AND `listings`.`lng` BETWEEN -0.40717687879372 AND 0.15165687879372
AND st_within(`listings_coords`.`coords`, @poly)

ORDER BY `created_at` 
LIMIT 10
```

However - when I perform a COUNT(`listings`.`listing_id`) for the given query it slows down from 0.03 to 4 seconds! I know InnoDB tends to be a bit slower than MyISAM on counting but this is far too long. Explain on the count:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                    | key                         | key_len | ref                            | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | listings        | ref    | PRIMARY,listings_country_id_foreign,latlng,listings_country_created_at,listings_compound,listings_lat_lng_country_created_at,listings_country_id_price_qualifier | listings_country_id_foreign | 4       | const                          | 10565 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | listings_coords | eq_ref | PRIMARY,coords                                                                                                                                                   | PRIMARY                     | 4       | cp_staging.listings.listing_id |     1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+-------------+
```

Is there any way I could get that number without having to take a decent nap during query execution?

Explain on the query without the count:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                    | key                         | key_len | ref                            | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | listings        | ref    | PRIMARY,listings_country_id_foreign,latlng,listings_country_created_at,listings_compound,listings_lat_lng_country_created_at,listings_country_id_price_qualifier | listings_country_created_at | 4       | const                          | 10565 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | listings_coords | eq_ref | PRIMARY,coords                                                                                                                                                   | PRIMARY                     | 4       | cp_staging.listings.listing_id |     1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+-------------+
```

Show create table listings:

```
CREATE TABLE `listings` (
  `listing_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `auth_agent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `branch_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `property_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `listings_status_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `listings_price_qualifier_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `listings_tenure_type_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `listings_class_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `listings_location_type_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_type` enum('1','2','3') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `auth_agents_staff_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `published_flag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `address_1` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_2` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `area` char(150) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `region` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `postcode` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `hide_address` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `street_view` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `lat` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `lng` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `listings_coords_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price_sales` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_sales_min` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_lettings` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_lettings_min` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_per_unit_sales` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_per_unit_lettings` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_size` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_size` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `listings_unit_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `summary` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `short_title` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `agent_ref` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `former_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coords` point DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`listing_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `listings_former_id_unique` (`former_id`),
  KEY `listings_price_sales_index` (`price_sales`),
  KEY `listings_price_sales_min_index` (`price_sales_min`),
  KEY `listings_price_lettings_index` (`price_lettings`),
  KEY `listings_price_lettings_min_index` (`price_lettings_min`),
  KEY `listings_country_id_foreign` (`country_id`),
  KEY `listings_agent_id_foreign` (`auth_agent_id`),
  KEY `listings_listings_status_id_foreign` (`listings_status_id`),
  KEY `listings_listings_price_qualifier_id_foreign` (`listings_price_qualifier_id`),
  KEY `listings_listings_unit_id_foreign` (`listings_unit_id`),
  KEY `listings_listings_tenure_type_id_foreign` (`listings_tenure_type_id`),
  KEY `agents_staff_id` (`auth_agents_staff_id`),
  KEY `listings_listings_class_id_foreign_idx` (`listings_class_id`),
  KEY `listings_listings_location_type_id_foreign_idx` (`listings_location_type_id`),
  KEY `listings_listings_branch_id_foreign_idx` (`branch_id`),
  KEY `latlng` (`lat`,`lng`),
  KEY `listings_city` (`city`,`created_at`),
  KEY `listings_country_created_at` (`country_id`,`created_at`),
  KEY `listings_transaction_type` (`transaction_type`),
  KEY `listings_compound` (`country_id`,`active`,`published_flag`,`created_at`),
  KEY `listings_lat_lng_country_created_at` (`lat`,`lng`,`country_id`,`created_at`),
  KEY `listings_country_id_price_qualifier` (`country_id`,`listings_price_qualifier_id`),
  KEY `country_active_published_property_type_lat_lng` (`country_id`,`active`,`published_flag`,`property_type`,`lat`,`lng`),
  KEY `country_active_published_flag_property_type_status_lat_lng` (`country_id`,`active`,`published_flag`,`property_type`,`listings_status_id`,`lat`,`lng`),
  CONSTRAINT `listings_agent_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`auth_agent_id`) REFERENCES `auth_agents` (`auth_agent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `listings_country_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `countries` (`country_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `listings_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`auth_agents_staff_id`) REFERENCES `agents_staff` (`agents_staff_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `listings_listings_branch_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`branch_id`) REFERENCES `branches` (`branch_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `listings_listings_class_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`listings_class_id`) REFERENCES `listings_classes` (`listings_class_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `listings_listings_location_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`listings_location_type_id`) REFERENCES `listings_location_types` (`listings_location_type_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `listings_listings_price_qualifier_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`listings_price_qualifier_id`) REFERENCES `listings_price_qualifiers` (`listings_price_qualifier_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `listings_listings_status_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`listings_status_id`) REFERENCES `listings_statuses` (`listings_status_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `listings_listings_tenure_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`listings_tenure_type_id`) REFERENCES `listings_tenure_types` (`listings_tenure_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `listings_listings_unit_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`listings_unit_id`) REFERENCES `listings_units` (`listings_unit_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34769 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Comment: How many rows do you have in your table? Is there a lot of write activity going on? MyISAM is a dangerous database to use with production data, it has no journal, no transactions, and can become irrecoverably corrupted in a server crash, so it's not really worth comparing theoretical times to it.

Comment: InnoDB is not slower at counting. The reason the select is faster is because you request for only 10 rows while the count query has no limit. Different queries, different execution plans, possibly different execution times.

Comment: Yeah.  Let's see the other `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 0):

this line is the culprit:

```
LIMIT 10
```

That's why your `select` is so fast.

Please remove this line and try it again. I assume that the `count`version is faster now.

Comment: I get that MySQL spends less time getting only 10 queries but due to the use of ORDER BY I figured it still has to go through all the rows and then pick them in the right order, doesn't it? Anyway the COUNT is still 0.5 sec slower then regular search (even with no limit)

Comment: @PeterStarling: not necessarily if you have an index on `created_at`

Comment: is there any way then to get that number without actually having to go through all the records? That is - is there a way to speed it up? It seems odd to me that an optimised query in a search engine would have to be executed without counting.

Comment: @PeterStarling well yes, especially if you have **no index**, then the result needs to be sorted before it is output. Sorting costs time, of course. However, if you have an index, then `order by` meansno more effort.

Comment: @SQLPolice any suggestions on how to get the count without the humongously low execution time?

Answer (score 0):

Without `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, I will make a few guesses...

- The `COUNT` is hundreds, maybe thousands?  That implies that `st_within()` had to be executed at least that many times.
- lat and lng fields are `NULLable`?  Can you make them `NOT NULL`?
- The latlng index is (lat, lng) and does not include the other three fields you are filtering on?  Putting them *first* in the index *may* help.  (This is the only real "answer" I am providing.)
- `created_at` is in `listings`?
- You ran the timings twice to avoid buffer caching, and used `SQL_NO_CACHE` to avoid the Query cache?  If not, the timings may be bogus.

How big (GB) are the tables?  What is the value of `key_buffer_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM?  (If the suitable buffer is not big enough that would lead to I/O instead of caching, hence a significant slowdown.)

Comment: The COUNT is exactly 1929 rows. Columns 'lat' and 'lng' are not nullable. I did put the following index: country_id-active-published_flag-lat-lng.

Comment: Explain shows the index is being used but unfortunately that didn't improve the performance. Also - the timings do not vary whether SQL_NO_CACHE is used or not.

And created_at is in listings, yeah. 
key_buffer_size = 8388608
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 134217728

Comment: Finally - I changed ST_WITHING to ST_INTERSECTS (apparently better optimised). I've notice a barely noticeable improvement. Is there any other way I could get the count? Let me also say its only for pagination purposes, perhaps I could get an approximate number somehow? (I am kind of desperate here!)